# Date in Spreadsheet shows as number when cell format is short date

Tags: excel

One spreadsheet in the workbook has a column of dates that appear as left justified numbers, even though the format on the column is Short Date.  Cannot set the column to number format, change alignment or force any other format.  When a cell is selected it shows as a date in the cell and in the formula bar, but when focus is changed, it reverts to number.  How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The spread sheet was copied from another workbook, and was apparently protected in that workbook.  Thus not able to format or change anything.  Ended up selecting all cells in the worksheet and pasting into a new worksheet.  Able to apply changes then.